# accessing Key vault stored credential from Azure Virual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-virtual-machine

Lets say I have an Azure VM and I have some client credential stored in a Azure key vault and I would like to access and use those credential from a python script in My Azure VM.. also I would like script to get updated stored credential whenever the credential changes in Key vault. So first question

1. is it possible to have a setup like above?
2. Would like to know the setup configuration as what resources to be deployed and necessary configuration step.
3. I have the script which can call Key vault secrets but how do i authenticate the key vault when calling it from an Azure VM.

Comment: It's quite broad question. Try to be more specific. What is not clear for you? How to read/write values to Key Vault? Or how to create Key Vault? Or how to update values in Key Vault?

Comment: Ok, elaborated  more in the question now.. more I am looking to get the setup and configuration correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it possible to have a setup like above?

Yes it is possible.

> 2. Would like to know the setup configuration as what resources to be deployed and necessary configuration step.

You need the following resources:

- An Azure VM (that will run your Python script)
- A User assigned managed identity (for authentication between VM and Keyvault)
- A keyvault (that will store your secret)

> 3. I have the script which can call Key vault secrets but how do i authenticate the key vault when calling it from an Azure VM.

As you already have a script, you need to add the user assigned managed identity in your Keyvault's access policies and attached the identity on your Azure VM. With this, your VM will be authorized to make API calls to the keyvault and will authenticate through the [Azure instance metadata service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/instance-metadata-service?tabs=windows) without the need to setup client secrets.

Use the following for reference:

https://blog.baeke.info/2023/01/07/authenticate-to-azure-resources-with-azure-managed-identities/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python